# Answering my own question?

Tags: support, questions, accepted-answer, self-answer

Am I allowed to answer my own question if I find out the answer by myself?

For example, if I ask a question about python and then figure out the answer do I answer my question or edit my post with the solution included.

Comment: Yes, answering your own question is perfectly fine.  For more details, see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: _Don't_ edit your question to include the solution. Add it as an answer.

Comment: See also: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)